# Run Time error 1004 'Copy method of Range Class Failed'

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, copy-paste

I am getting the following error in my code

> Run Time error 1004 'Copy method of Range Class Failed'

What the code does is it allows a user to click on a command button that opens up a txt box and allows a user to select a file from file directory.

The second piece of code then goes through column F of the selected workbook and finds a country and then creates a new sheet copies and pastes the data for that country into the new sheet and names that sheet for the country then returns to column F and repeats for other countries.
The sheet is MASSIVE over 280,000 rows if the sheet is at 65,000 or less the Macro runs perfectly but anything over and we get

> Run Time error 1004 'Copy method of Range Class Failed'

The code bugs at `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1") 'copy data for country under header`
Can my code be amended to to accommodate the large number of rows

```
Sub Open_Workbook_Dialog()

Dim my_FileName As Variant

    MsgBox "Pick your TOV file" '<--| txt box for prompt to pick a file

        my_FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*") '<--| Opens the file window to allow selection

    If my_FileName <> False Then
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=my_FileName

Call Filter '<--|Calls the Filter Code and executes

End If

End Sub

Public Sub Filter()
    Dim rCountry As Range, helpCol As Range

    With Worksheets("CountryList") '<--| refer to data worksheet
        With .UsedRange
            Set helpCol = .Resize(1, 1).Offset(, .Columns.Count) '<--| get a "helper" column just at the right of used range, it'll be used to store unique country names in
        End With

        With .Range("A1:Q" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).Row) '<--| refer to its columns "A:Q" from row 1 to last non empty row of column "A"
            .Columns(6).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=helpCol, Unique:=True '<-- call AdvancedFilter on 6th column of the referenced range and store its unique values in "helper" column
            Set helpCol = Range(helpCol.Offset(1), helpCol.End(xlDown)) '<--| set range with unique names in (skip header row)
            For Each rCountry In helpCol '<--| iterate over unique country names range (skip header row)
                .AutoFilter 6, rCountry.Value2 '<--| filter data on country field (6th column) with current unique country name
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells.Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell other than header ones has been filtered...
                    Worksheets.Add Worksheets(Worksheets.Count) '<--... add new sheet
                    ActiveSheet.Name = rCountry.Value2  '<--... rename it
                    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1") 'copy data for country under header
                End If
            Next
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False '<--| remove autofilter and show all rows back
    End With
    helpCol.Offset(-1).End(xlDown).Clear '<--| clear helper column (header included)
End Sub
```

Comment: If possible use higher version of Excel 2007,2012..

Comment: @Siva: Thank you for the response I am currently Using Excel 2010

Comment: `With .Range("A1:Q" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).Row)` does **not** refer to the *'last non empty row of column "A"'*. It refers to the entire worksheet of rows. You need to add `.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: @Jeeped, the full comment of that (admittedly,very clever...) coder is _"refers to columns "A:Q" from row 1 to last non empty row of column "A""_. That is right, isn't it?

Comment: @user3598756 - No it is not. the full code line should be `With .Range("A1:Q" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)` or you shouldn't close off the `With .UsedRange`.

Comment: @Jeeped: aarrgh! not that clever at the end...

Comment: Philip, mind @Jeeped comment. i.e.: change `With .Range("A1:Q" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).Row)` with `With .Range("A1:Q" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)`

Comment: @Jeeped & User3598756: WOW I mean WOW you guys really are amazing!! I can only dream of such a skill set.  Thank you guys so much it works amazing well and it processes really quickly. Again much respect from Dublin Ireland. Have a great Monday :-)